# Need to install HDF5 library 1.8.16 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-library

I need to run an older software that requires this specific version of HDF5 library. But Ubuntu 18 already consists 1.10.0-patch 1, which is a higher version. So in result I get:

"Headers are 1.8.16, library is 1.10.0"

The only source I found for 1.8.16 version is here: https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.8/hdf5-1.8.16/obtain51816.html. But I don't know how would it work with Ubuntu 18.04.

I am still very new to Linux, and would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked are for binaries built for CentOS 6, CentOS 7 and Windows, if you must use Ubuntu 18.04 then you would want binaries built for Ubuntu.

I found the [Ubuntu repository has your desired version of `hdf5`](http://ubuntu.cs.utah.edu/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hdf5/) but I cannot confirm that it is built for your specific version of Ubuntu.